# Override index include column postgresql and ef core

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm using entity framework core for SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

And I need to override create index with include columns.

I use NpgsqlMigrationsAnnotationProvider and NpgsqlMigrationsSqlGenerator to do this.

My code is

NpgsqlMigrationsSqlGenerator

Generate function:

```
        base.Generate(operation, model, builder, false);
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        var includeIndexAnnotation = operation.FindAnnotation("IncludeIndex");

        if (includeIndexAnnotation != null)
        {
            var includeColumns = includeIndexAnnotation.Value.ToString().Split(",");
            var includeOperation = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append(" INCLUDE(");
            foreach (var includeColumn in includeColumns)
            {
                if (includeOperation.Length > 0)
                    includeOperation.Append(",");
                includeOperation.Append($"\"{includeColumn}\"");
            }
            includeOperation.Append(")");
            builder.Append(includeOperation);
        }

        if (terminate)
        {
            builder.AppendLine(StatementTerminator);
            EndStatement(builder);
        }
```

And

NpgsqlMigrationsAnnotationProvider

For(IIndex index) function:

```
        var baseAnnotations = base.For(index);
        var customAnnotations = index.GetAnnotations().Where(a => a.Name == "IncludeIndex");
        return baseAnnotations.Concat(customAnnotations);
```

Extensions:

```
 public static IndexBuilder Include<TEntity>(this IndexBuilder indexBuilder, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> indexExpression)
    {
        var includeStatement = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var column in indexExpression.GetPropertyAccessList())
        {
            if (includeStatement.Length > 0)
                includeStatement.Append(",");

            includeStatement.AppendFormat("{0}", column.Name);
        }

        indexBuilder.HasAnnotation("IncludeIndex", includeStatement.ToString());

        return indexBuilder;
    }
```

DesignTimeDbContextFactory:

```
   builder.ReplaceService<IMigrationsAnnotationProvider, PostgreSql.DbMigrationsAnnotationProvider>();
                builder.ReplaceService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, PostgreSql.DbMigrationsSqlGenerator>();
```

DbContext:

```
   entity.HasIndex(log => new { log.Id }).Include<Log>(log => new { log.Type, log.Source, log.Created, log.Message })
```

This code working fine with sql server but not working with postgresql.
Can't add Include command to CreateIndex query.
Thanks for your support.

Comment: What is the error you get? Which Postgres version are you using? The `include` option for `create index` was only just added with the most recent version (11)

Comment: yes, i'm using postgresql version 11. No error when i run Update-Database -Verbose in Package Manager Console. But query can't generate Include command to Create Index query. Query generated is: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "IX_Logs_201902_Id" ON "Logs_201902" ("Id");

Comment: When i use Debug.Launch. Debugger not run to For(IIndex index) and Generate function. Sorry if my English not good.